# Efficient method to calculate green's function between points

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, code-review

I am working on an analytical model for sound radiation from a cylinder. As part of this work I am using the boundary element method to predict the sound pressure at a particular location away from a vibrating cylinder.

This requires the cylinder to be split into a number of elements and a function to be evaluated which is dependent on the vectors between the centroid of each element and a selected location in space. Therefore I ultimately require a n x 1 matrix (where n is the number of elements the cylinder is split into).

I have managed to produce what I require using the below code, however, this appears (to me) to be a very inefficient method as the code produces a n x n matrix and then cuts this down to a n x 1 matrix. In this case the extra elements of the n x n matrix are not required. My method is outlined below.

Variables to be defined;

- ro, θo, zo = the r , theta and z coordinates of the point of
  interest.
- nn and mm are used to divide the cylinder up into nn x mm elements.
- a = cylinder radius; L = cylinder length; co = speed of sound (343); ω = frequency of vibration

.

```
a = 0.1096; nn = 1; mm = 4; L = 1.408; co = 343; ω = 500; ko =ω/co; ro = 3; θo = π/4; zo = 4;
```

Then randomList creates a list of all the elements centroids and the point of interest,

```
randomList = Prepend[Flatten[
Table[{a, (i*π)/mm, (j*L)/(2*nn)}, {i, 1, 2*mm, 2}, {j, 1, 
  2*nn}], 1], {ro, θo, zo}];
```

Now ggr[] is the function which I wish to apply to the randomList. Ideally this function would only be evaluated for the vectors between element 1 and element 2, 3, 4, etc. of randomList.

```
ggr[{a1_, a2_, a3_}, {b1_, b2_, 
b3_}] := (-(1/4*π*
    Sqrt[(a1*Cos[a2] - b1*Cos[b2])^2 + (a1*Sin[a2] - 
          b1*Sin[b2])^2 + (a3 - b3)^2]^2) - ((I*ko)/4*π*
   Sqrt[(a1*Cos[a2] - b1*Cos[b2])^2 + (a1*Sin[a2] - 
        b1*Sin[b2])^2 + (a3 - b3)^2]))*Exp[-I*ko*
 Sqrt[(a1*Cos[a2] - b1*Cos[b2])^2 + (a1*Sin[a2] - 
      b1*Sin[b2])^2 + (a3 - b3)^2]];
```

Finally the following code produces the matrix I require by first calculating a n x n matrix and then extracting the required information out to produce the final n x 1 matrix,

```
Take[Transpose[Take[Table[
  ggr[randomList[[i]], randomList[[j]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[randomList], 2}, {j, 1, Length[randomList], 2}], {1, 
  1}]], {2, mm*nn + 1}] // MatrixForm
```

Is there a more efficient way to directly calculate the required n x 1 matrix?

Comment: Have you looked at `GreenFunction[]`?

Comment: I have looked at `GreenFunction[]`, I thought it would be easier to write out the `ggr[]` function, which is the derivative of the Green's function, rather than use `GreenFunction[]` in it's place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken your final expression may be reduced to:

```
Table[
  { ggr[ randomList[[1]], randomList[[1 + 2 j]] ] },
  {j, mm*nn}
]
```

> ```
> {{-7.01292 - 10.5223 I},
>  {-8.64938 - 9.92198 I},
>  {-10.2158 - 9.0987 I},
>  {-8.64938 - 9.92198 I}}
> ```

Or equivalently:

```
Array[{ggr[randomList[[1]], randomList[[1 + 2 #]]]} &, mm*nn]
```